# JSF passing large number of parameters from one page to other

Tags: jsf, redirect, parameters, forward

I want to pass a large number of parameters from one JSF page to another.

For lower number of parameters I use ExternalContext#redirect() in an listener method with a url containing the parameters like this:

```
 FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/faces/someDir/index.jsf?p1=a&p2=b");
```

If I do the same with large number of parameters it doesn't work. My understanding is, that the browser has a restriction on the size of the URL. If the URL has more tahn approx. 2000 characerts it doesn't work.

I tried a forward like

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().dispatch("/faces/someDir/index.jsf?p1=a&p2=b");
```

but then the target page works on the data of the source page. Reason for this could be the my software archticture, which I can not explain in detail here...

My questions: Has anyone had a similar problem and a solution for this?

Comment: I guess this is the answer you need: http://serverfault.com/questions/56691/whats-the-maximum-url-length-in-tomcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send a large number of parameters accross more pages, then it's better to encapsulate them into a session scoped bean instead of sending them as GET parameters.

For example:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SESSION_Bean_Class {

    // Declare members
    // all parameters
    private int p1;
    private int p2;
    private String p3;
    private String p4;

    // Getter(s) and Setter(s)
    public int getP1() {
        return p1;
    }
    public void setP1(int p1) {
        this.p1 = p1;
    }
    public int getP2() {
        return p2;
    }
    public void setP2(int p2) {
        this.p2 = p2;
    }
    public String getP3() {
        return p3;
    }
    public void setP3(String p3) {
        this.p3 = p3;
    }
    public String getP4() {
        return p4;
    }
    public void setP4(String p4) {
        this.p4 = p4;
    }
}
```

Then you can access them easily at any page like follows:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
</h:head>
<h:body>
    Value parameter 1 is That #{sESSION_Bean_Class.p1}
    <br />
    Value parameter 2 is That #{sESSION_Bean_Class.p2}
    <br />
    Value parameter 3 is That #{sESSION_Bean_Class.p3}
    <br />
    Value parameter 4 is That #{sESSION_Bean_Class.p4}
    <br />  
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much - this is a way to solve the problem. I haven't thought about to put the data into the session, because I avoid session variables if ever possible. But in this case it seems to be necessary. Thanx